# Calling ros::spin from a new Thread

Tags: ros, multi-thread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

i have a strange problem with ROS. I am trying to subscribe to a ros topic in my application. Since the spin-method blocks the application i just started a new thread and tried to subscribe to the topic within this new thread. Here is my code:

```
void MatlabDevice::startROSCommunication() {
    boost::thread t(&MatlabDevice::startROSThread, this);
}

void MatlabDevice::startROSThread() {
    ros::NodeHandle nodeH;
    nodeH.subscribe("chatter", 1000, &MatlabDevice::callbackBodyMessage, this);
    ros::spin();
}

void MatlabDevice::callbackBodyMessage(const biorob_msgs::BioBipedBody::ConstPtr &msg) {
   // Further code here
}
```

The strange thing is that this worked some time ago. Now i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1352133007.566663012]: SingleThreadedSpinner: You've attempted to call spin from multiple threads.  Use a MultiThreadedSpinner instead.
```

I tried to remove the spin() call and used the MultiThreadedSpinner but this gives me:

```
[ERROR] [1352133281.107900251]: MultiThreadeSpinner: You've attempted to call ros::spin from multiple threads... but this spinner is already multithreaded.
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Greetings, Simon.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47505/calling-ros::spin-from-a-new-thread/) by [mikemodanoxxx](https://answers.ros.org/users/2315/mikemodanoxxx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should only call spin from a single thread.  You might now have two instances of this class or another class which now follows the same patter.  If you want to do this It's suggested to use the multithreaded Spinner.  [See the overview page for threading](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2